# Consumer optimization problems with multiples cases

Tags: consumer-theory

Does anyone know of any resources where the Lagrangian optimization of the consumer problem with one constraint has two cases for an answer? For example, when income is greater than x, the optimal condition is this. When income = y, the optimal condition is this. Trying to study for a midterm! Thanks.

Comment: See Quasilinear preferences - https://qr.ae/pGJuvH